# gcloud: show quota limits for SimulateMaintenanceEvent

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sdk

Is there a way to see `Instance SimulateMaintenanceEvent requests per day` quota limit (and its current usage) by gcloud cli?

`gcloud compute project-info describe --project myproject` does not contain this information.

Thanks in advance.

P.S 
`gcloud compute regions describe [REGION]` doesn't help either.

Comment: Documentation says it should https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas  if its not sounds like a bug

Comment: Compute Engine quotes are usually regional. Try the regional command `gcloud compute regions describe [REGION]`

Comment: @JohnHanley Checked. It doesn't contains that info either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to check your current quota limits in the Google Cloud Console:

1. Using GCP console [Quota page](https://console.cloud.google.com/quotas) or [APIs & Services page](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/dashboard)
2. Using 'gcloud' commands: 'gcloud compute project-info describe --project myproject' and 'gcloud compute regions describe [REGION]'.

Unfortunately, 'gcloud' command output does not consist SimulateMaintenanceEvent quota information.

You can file a Feature Request [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#search_for_or_create_issues_and_feature_requests_by_product) if you want to add this quota info in 'gcloud' command output.